# c++ Vector declared private in class but has a get function

Tags: c++, function, vector

If I have a class lets say like this in a separate `.h` file

```
class myclass{
  private:
     vector<string> data;
  public:
     vector <string>& getMydata(){
       return this->data;
     }
};
```

How do I then in separate `.cpp` access the data in the private vector?

Comment: All functions, member functions or not, have access to it via the public member function `getMydata()`. I don't get the question really ... As it is right now you could just have made `data` public.

Comment: You've answered your own question. Private data is only visible to the owning class, but it can be exposed by public methods and members, such as how you've done using `myclass::getMyData`. Why would you do this? By making the raw data hidden, you can add constraints such as only exposing read-only access (if `getMyData` returns a `const vector<string>&`)

Comment: i guess i meant to say in main.cpp how would i access the vector  would i have to i have tried declaring an object like myclass mynewdata; the doing mynewdata.getMydata()[0]; and this does not work.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify these details, as well as add your few lines of code from main. What do you mean by _it doesn't work_. The code you posted in your comment won't work because the vector is empty, but it will compile.

Answer (score 1):

`the.hpp`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class myclass{
private:
     std::vector<std::string> data;

public:
     // put some data in it when it's default constructed
     myclass() : data{"hello", "world"} {}

     std::vector<std::string>& getMydata() {
         return data;
     }
};
```

`main.cpp`

```
#include "the.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    myclass instance;

    // get reference to the data in the instance
    std::vector<std::string>& data_ref = instance.getMydata();

    // use the data. data_ref is a reference to exactly the same vector as in "instance"
    data_ref.push_back("Someone from the utside was here!");

    // check result
    std::cout << instance.getMydata()[0] << "\n";
    std::cout << instance.getMydata()[1] << "\n";
    std::cout << instance.getMydata()[2] << "\n";   
}
```

Output:

```
hello
world
Someone from the utside was here!
```

Comment: thank you i just realized the reason i was getting the undefined error was because i wasnt compiling the appropriate .cpp files

Comment: @theGOATofJOAT You are welcome! I didn't see any undefined error in the question though?

Comment: what if the vector already has stuff in it, would i still use the instance.getMydata()[0] because as of right now im getting a segment fault

Comment: @theGOATofJOAT If you do, you are most probably accessing the vector out of bounds. Check my update. With 3 elements in the vector, you can access it using the substript operator using 0, 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

You separate the implementation into a `.cpp` the same way you do any function:

```
vector <string>& myClass::getMydata(){
    return this->data;
}
```

The only difference it you'll need to show that you are implementing the one from the class by putting `myClass::` in front of your implementation.

The compiler will allow a member function to access `private` data, even if it is defined outside the class definition.

---

> i understand that. I guess what i mean to say is in main.cpp how would access the data?

Oh, I see. If you want to access it from `main()`, or some other non-member function, you need to call your getter:

```
int main() {
    myclass foo;

    foo.getMydata().push_back("We're modifying the vector from main()!");
}
```

Comment: i understand that. I guess what i mean to say is in main.cpp how would access the data?